# Is it possible to change the repo path (metadata) of a cloned pipeline in Azure Devops?

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

First off, I'm new to this so be nice. ;-)
I have created one pipeline from the branch of an existing repository built within Azure DevOps that successfully builds. Call it Repo1

Now I have another app that has a similar architecture, framework and etc. in another repo. Call it Repo2

So I cloned the Repo1 pipeline and renamed everything based on Repo2. E.g. The pipeline name, the directory I store it in and etc.

Everything looks great but when I attempt to edit the pipeline, it fails to load because it's looking for the YAML file in the path of Repo1.

I can't seem to find any way to edit the cloned pipeline to change the path and name of the repo it should be looking at to properly launch the editor.

So am I approaching this wrong or is there a way to change/edit the metadata of the cloned pipeline to correct the repo path, name and etc?

I've already search SO but couldn't find the answer. If I've somehow overlooked a potential dupe, let me know.

```
**An error occurred while fetching the YAML file 'Repo2/ci-pipeline.yml' in the repository's default branch and latest build branches: master. 
Error on the last attempt: File Repo2/pipelines/ci-pipeline.yml not found in repository Repo1 
at version/branch master.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case (at least) 1 repo is to 1 azure-pipelines.yml. You might be editing the pipeline for repo1, you should use `New Pipeline` for your repo2

Comment: Ok, so my approach is obviously incorrect and there is no way to edit the repo path once the pipeline is created. thx